# How to export a node.js function in an azure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, refactoring

I have the following structure with 2 azure functions running separately in an azure function app:

```
- main_function_app
  - functions
    - Full_Stack
        - configAPI.json
        - configAPITest.json
        - function.json
        - index.js
    - Web  
        - configAPI.json
        - configAPITest.json
        - function.json
        - index.js
    - host.json
    - local.settings.json
    - package-lock.json
    - package.json
    - proxies.json
    - utils.js
```

I have the following content in the `index.js` from `Full_Stack`:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) { 
    let element = req.body;
    const purchase_time = Number(element.purchase_time_);
    const type = "Full Stack";

    if (element.startswith('full')){
        async function getStatusPayload(purchase_time, offset);
    }

    async function getStatusPayload(purchase_time, type){
    if (purchase_time>0){
        context.log("Purchase time successful in " + type);
        }
    }
    context.res = {
       // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
       status: 200
    };
}
```

I have the following content in the `index.js` from `Web`:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) { 
    let element = req.body;
    const purchase_time = Number(element.purchase_time_);
    const type = "Web";

    if (element.startswith('web')){
       async function getStatusPayload(purchase_time, type); 
    }

    async function getStatusPayload(purchase_time, type){
    if (purchase_time>0){
        context.log("Purchase time successful in " + type);
        }
    }
    context.res = {
       // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
       status: 200
    };
}
```

Both functions are almost the same and I want to refactor the `getStatusPayload`. I have created a draft in the `utils.js` file but I cannot test it in the either the full stack or web index.js because I don't know how to import it from azure. Also, I am not totally sure if code will even work once I am able to import it to full stack and web.

```
// utils.js
exports ={
    getStatusPayload: async function (purchase_time, type){
    if (purchase_time>0){
        context.log("Purchase time successful in " + type);
        }
      }
   }
}
module.exports = exports;
```

I also came around `context.executionContext.functionDirectory` which throws the current directory, but not sure if this might be helpful in in the solution.

Comment: [Azure Functions JavaScript developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2-v3-v4-export%2Cv2-v3-v4-done%2Cv2%2Cv2-log-custom-telemetry%2Cv2-accessing-request-and-response%2Cwindows-setting-the-node-version#dependency-management) tried?

Comment: It seems I need to add a script file. I have applied the changes but how should I write the `utils.js` file? I don't think my syntax is correct.

Comment: Bit too long for comment. I answered normally.

Answer (score 1):

To your question: require is a function we can use to import other modules:

```
// it looks like this
let util = require('./util.js');
```

and to export:

```
function getStatusPayload() {
    // Code here
}

module.exports = {
    getStatusPayload
}
```